# Login trouble using Android and Google keychain

Tags: support, bug

I use a google account as a keychain for all my passwords. Until now, I was able to log into stack exchange on both my MacBook Air and my Android phone using this keychain. Today, I am able to log into stack exchange using my MacBook air, but not using it on Android. When I pull up the login screen on my Android, the email field auto-fills, but the password field remains unfilled. I have tried various no-brain solutions like rebooting, clearing cache, etc. to no avail. Auto logging in on other sites, such as facebook and X are working fine on my Android. Just stack exchange seems to have a problem.

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Edit: Per a suggestion by SamGibson, I tested an older version of the login window on my Android using the WayBack Machine. Using this older version of the login window, both the email field AND the password field were populated.

Comment: (For the benefit of anyone else reading this, the OP has followed my [suggestion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10023) and asked this as a [question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398658/login-failure-using-google-password-keychain-on-android). Anyone interested in this issue can click "follow" on that one.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't use the same password management, so I haven't seen that issue.

However, if it's only affecting SE now and not other sites, and if it used to work on SE in the past, it seems possible (maybe even likely) that the cause may be change in SE website code. We don't get notified when that happens. At the moment, I *think* the latest change to the front-end code was 22 March i.e. the day you posted this question. Interesting coincidence...

Since I can't reproduce it, the SE procedures don't allow me to escalate it to SE for you. (It's possible one of the other mods can reproduce it, so I'm only speaking for me.)

As this isn't an issue specific to EE.SE then I recommend you ask it on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). I looked there and did not see a similar problem being described. Therefore I don't think a new question from you would be a duplicate.

Comment: Since I have followed your advice and posted this question on Meta.SE, I am a bit unsure about what I should do with this question. Accept your answer? Close the question? Leave it as is until there is resolution of the underlying problem?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy - I'm not sure either :) Strictly, this one shouldn't be open, as it duplicates the one on Meta.SE. But since you asked here originally, it's always possible that someone here has the same setup as you, they might not monitor Meta.SE and they might be able to help. || If someone else shuts this down, then that's understandable. However I don't see the harm (now that there's a link to the "main" Meta.SE question), in leaving this open - at least for a while - in case someone reads it here and goes to Meta.SE to help. (I made a troubleshooting suggesting on your Meta.SE post.)